# Something is changing my search results in all browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, malware

For a few days now, I experience the following symptoms:

1. Whenever I type a search term in the omnibox, some of the times I am being redirected to a search engine named "secure-surf.net", instead of the normal google which is set on all browser for me.

   - This happens now in chrome, firefox
   - I actually see, google being opened first, and then, something redirects that other secure-surf.net engine.
2. Even when a normal google search takes place, the results are being modified. Some fake unrelated results are being added as the first few results.
   And again, I see regular true releveant results appear, and then before my eyes, few fake ones are being added to the page. This happens on an actual *google* search.

Steps that I took:

- Full system scan with: avast antivirus (updated db), malwarebytes, zemana antimalware. No problem found by any of them.
- Checked for unknown extensions on chrome. Did not find anything I don't know or trust. Neither anything new
- Tried searching from an incognito window. Symptom #2 above, happens there as well.
- Start → Control Panel → Network and Internet → Internet Options → Connections → LAN Settings - does not show any proxy set

Please help me to debug the situation, suggest further steps.

Comment: who is your ISP? There are some ISPs in some countries which will rewrite responses and inject javascript iframes etc.

Comment: check your browser add-ons most likely ad-ware. delete any that you did not install yourself or remove them one-by-one to find the culprit.

Comment: Are there any other devices in the same LAN? Do they have the same problem?

Comment: Thank you for the beneficial question, sam. The answer is: there are more devices. I did not observe the situatuation happening there

Comment: @Yorik , no change of the ISP. This would also be very problematic if this mainstream Israeli isp would have been doing such a something

Comment: @Joe I disabled all extensions. No change

Comment: Has the DNS address been changed? I imagine it should be auto set by your ISP or manually set (hopefully by you). [Open DNS](https://www.opendns.com/) is a reliable option, and you don't have to worry about what your ISP is doing.

Answer (score 1):

After experiencing the same problem and going through a process of disabling chrome extensions, I found it to be the Chrome Apps Launcher extension to be the culprit. This also made a load of ads appear at the top of the google images search page, with the image thumbnails only appearing a full page scroll down the results. Disabled Apps Launcher extension and all is back to normal. This problem started on a brand new laptop so a little surprised to be getting these problems. Malwarebytes and Chrome Clean-up Computer functions found nothing